# SQL one-to-many JOIN / Aggregate

Tags: mysql, group-by, one-to-many, aggregate

I have an Events table, with basic info and an Event.ID

I then have multiple categories, which I am using as 'tags'.

```
Event_Categories (stores each 'tag')
 - id
 - name

Events_Categories (links tags to event ID)
 - event_id
 - event_category_id
```

I need to perform an SQL query, which will return the Event information, along with all the tags.

```
SELECT  * FROM `events`
 JOIN (`event_categories` 
 JOIN `events_categories` ON `event_categories`.`id` = `events_categories`.`event_category_id` )  
 ON `events`.`id` = `events_categories`.`event_id`
```

Returns the 'Events' multiple times, with each individual tag.

when I append `GROUP BY event_categories.name`, it returns distinct events, but only shows one tag.

I'm sure this has been covered on here, but searching through, I can't find the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `group_concat()` to get the list of category names:

```
SELECT e.*, group_concat(c.name)
FROM `events` e JOIN 
     `events_categories` ec
     ON e.`id` = ec.`event_id` join
     `event_categories` c
     on ec.`event_category_id` = c.`id`
group by e.`id`;
```

EDIT:

To do this as an outer join to get all events even when there are no tags on it, just replace the `join` with `left join`:

```
select e.*, group_concat(c.name)
from `events` e left join 
     `events_categories` ec
     ON e.`id` = ec.`event_id` left join
     `event_categories` c
     on ec.`event_category_id` = c.`id`
group by e.`id`;
```

Comment: Awesome & thanks for the edit. One more brain-picking however, if you don't mind.. When I add a WHERE clause (`e.id=x`), it returns specific event with all the tags as expected. BUT when I search by tagnames using `c.name IN ("either","tag")` it returns event, but not all tags associated with that event, only the ones I searched for, if this makes sense? thanks

Comment: @BigDistance . . . If you add a `where` clause on the tag names, then you will get only those tags.  If you want to get all events that have a certain set of tags, then ask another question, because that is quite different from this question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help @gorden-linoff . It is best that these are in separate functions anyway. I've posted a new Q: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047093/)