# SQL One-To-Many return & group by search condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation, one-to-many

**Hello again beloved overflowers, I hope we have some brains available for the picking; as always it's greatly appreciated! :)**

I have an Events table, which can be assigned multiple categories (used as tags):

I then have the Categories (stores each tag) and Events_Categories (linking table)

```
**Events**
| id  | event_name |
+------------+
+ 1   | Basketball
+ 2   | Children Charity Ball
+ 3   | Bowling Charity Event


**Event_Categories** (Stores Tags / Categories)
| id  | name |
+------------+
+ 1   | sport
+ 2   | charity
+ 3   | other_tag


**Events_Categories** (Linking Table)
| event_id  | event_category_id |
+-------------------------------+
+    1      |       1   
+    2      |       2   
+    3      |       1   
+    3      |       2
```

**Summary of above**

```
Basketball            => Sports 
Children Charity Ball => Charity 
Bowling Charity       => Charity & Sports
```

**Desired Result**

I want to be able to search for 'Sport' tag, which would return all events which have that tag. BUT, it needs to return (and group) all the tags associated with that particular event.

IE searching for 'Sport' tag would return:

```
**Events**
| id  |       event_name      |  tags         |
+---------------------------------------------+
+ 1   | Basketball            | sport
+ 3   | Bowling Charity Event | sport, charity
```

**SQL Example returning Events without WHERE conditions:**
The following SQL, returns all events and groups the categories (or tags). This should give you an idea of my DB structure, possibly help with the solution?

```
SELECT e.*, group_concat(c.name) as tags
FROM `events` e 
JOIN `events_categories` ec
    ON e.`id` = ec.`event_id` 
JOIN `event_categories` c
     ON ec.`event_category_id` = c.`id`
GROUP BY e.`id`;
```

**Additional Question (for extra brownie points)**

**Can you believe it, HE WANTS MORE HELP!! :)**

Also, in the linking table, there is actually  another field for when the events link to an Activity:

```
**Events_Categories** (Linking Table)
| event_id  | event_category_id | activity_id |
+---------------------------------------------+
+    1      |       1           |     1
+    2      |       2           |
+    3      |       1           |     2
+    3      |       2           |     2
```

How would I search for an event, with the Activity ID of [x] to return the event details, again with all the tags grouped:

**Events which link to Activity_ID of 2 associated**

```
| id  |       event_name      |  tags          | activity_id |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 3   | Bowling Charity Event | sport, charity |     2
```

Thanks so much, once again!

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: what RDMBS are you using?

Comment: @491243 - I have updated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will answer the first part of your question. In order to get the list of all categories contain in an event, you can use `EXISTS` to check if the event contains atleast a portion of your search event name.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Event_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name)
FROM    Events a
        INNER JOIN Events_Categories b
            ON a.ID = b.event_ID
        INNER JOIN Event_Categories c
            ON b.event_category_id = c.ID
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Events_Categories d
                    INNER JOIN Event_Categories e
                        ON d.event_category_id = e.id 
            WHERE   e.Name = 'Sport' AND
                    d.event_id = a.id
        )
GROUP   BY  a.ID,
            a.Event_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8510d/3)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Event_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name) CategoryList,
        MAX(activity_id) activity_id
FROM    Events a
        INNER JOIN Events_Categories b
            ON a.ID = b.event_ID
        INNER JOIN Event_Categories c
            ON b.event_category_id = c.ID
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.Event_name
HAVING  MAX(activity_id) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e41f9/3)

Comment: for the second part of the question, is it possible for an event to have different `activity_id`?

Comment: Events will only have ONE (if any) `activity_id`. Activities are more like Groups. IE our football team, which on their activity page, would display associated Events. Tagging in this SQL statement would be irrelevant (but tagging would bring better awareness to the events on the /tag/search)

Comment: so in the second part, you dont need to search for tags?

Comment: Correct, second SQL would need to find `events` associated with the `activity_id`. Also again, grouping the tags.

Comment: So much help, thanks. However pt2 gives me SQL error near 'activity_id = 2. Any ideas? thx

Comment: sorry for the typo, it should be `HAVING  MAX(activity_id) = 2`

Comment: I should've realised that. Thanks once again, your help has been invaluable. - need to avoid chat but equally express my gratitude!